# formidable can only process one file?

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am trying to use formidable to parse a form with multiple files upload, but somehow the result only shows one file. Here is the parsing code I copied directly from example here:
https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

```
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.multiples = true; // per their documents
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files})); // files only contain one file,
  // and files.length is undefined. It is not an array. 
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <FORM action="/file"
       enctype="multipart/form-data"
       method="post">
   <br>
   What is your name? 
   <INPUT type="text" name="kk1_submit-name"><BR>

   What files are you sending? 
   <INPUT type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploads"><BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Upload"> 

 </FORM>
```

The output json object only has one file object, and files.length is undefined, even I select 5 files to upload. This middleware is well tested, I think I must've made a mistake somewhere.

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `formidable` module began to support for uploading multiple files a month ago. But the `formidable` module in `npmjs.org` was updated 11 months ago. So you need to install the latest `formidable` manually.

```
git clone  git://github.com/felixge/node-formidable.git node_modules/formidable
```

Now run the application again and you should get the right output:

```
received upload:

{ fields: { title: '' },
  files: { upload: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

Comment: I see. That's the problem. How often does NPM update its repository?

Comment: The maintainers of `formidable` decide when to publish the new version of this module.

Answer (score 2):

Since time of writing, the Formidable library has undergone changes. You must now explicitly set some parameters of the IncomingForm object, most notably:

- multiples:true

If you want to bypass file size:

- maxFileSize:(about in bytes (not maxFieldsSize) )

This enables you to use the latest version of formidable properly

Answer (score 0):

I switched to node-multiparty, a form parser folked from formidable. The number of files uploaded is correct. 
So maybe it is a bug for formidable. Use node-multiparty can save you some time.

[image]